# Problems with SDL rendering frames

Tags: c++, sprite, sdl

I'm still a somewhat beginner in SDL, and I've come accross a problem that I am little lost on. I've been loosely following LazyFoo's tutorials along with some other additional resources.

The problem is trying to create an animated sprite onto a window. 
I managed to isolate the malfunctioning code to whenever I press a key down.
When I press a key down, a new window opens up in addition to the one previously intialized using the SDL_CreateWindow function.

```
case SDL_KEYDOWN:
        int frame = 0;
        //Clear Screen
        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF);
        SDL_RenderClear(renderer);

        //Render Current frame
        SDL_Rect* currentFrame = &iKey.MegamanRun[frame / 6];
        iKey.mmxrender((sx - currentFrame->w) / 2, (sy - currentFrame->h) / 2, currentFrame);


        //update screen
        SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);

        //Next frame
        ++frame;
```

I'm using a simple megaman sprite, if that helps you understand some of the names.

Specifically, the

```
iKey.mmxrender((sx - currentFrame->w) / 2, (sy - currentFrame->h) / 2, currentFrame);
```

is causing new windows to pop up.

the mmxrender function is in a different class on a different file, sx and sy are the size of the window.

```
void Megaman::mmxrender(int x, int y, SDL_Rect* clip)
{
Init mkey;
//Set rendering space
SDL_Rect renderQuad = { x, y, iWidth, iHeight };

//Set clip dimensions
if (clip != NULL)
{
    renderQuad.w = clip->w;
    renderQuad.h = clip->h;
}
//Render to screen

SDL_RenderCopy(mkey.renderer, iTexture, clip, &renderQuad); 
}
```

Not sure how to proceed, any help is appreciated.

Comment: I don't want a series of neverending windows to open when I run the program. I'm trying to plot an animated sprite onto a window with SDL, but I've come into this weird bug.

Comment: Anything in the constructor or destructor of the `Init` class that would create a new window?

Comment: Oh. I'm so silly. Earlier I was dealing with problems involving circular dependencies between classes and solved it by including an object in functions that required it. Failed to realize that it would also trigger the constructor every time it looped haha.

Comment: The simplest way to resolve an issue like that is to declare (but not define) the `Init` class inside the `Megaman` _header_ file and include the `Init` header inside the `Megaman` _source_ file. Then it's your choice between passing an `Init*` into the constructor and storing it or into the rendering method.